# initWithURL is unavailable: not available in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode4, xcode5

I am getting the error:
initWithURL is unavailable: not available in IOS
on following line:

```
 HomeViewController *wBrowser = [[HomeViewController alloc]        initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

This happened when i switched my application code from Xcode 4.X to Xcode 5.1.1
And, this activity is required to distribute the app via iTunes.

Please suggest

Comment: initWithURL its not a UIViewController method. make sure you have declare this method in HomeViewController

Comment: Please Specify that what you want exactly.............

Answer (score 2):

`InitWithURL:` is not a method of `UIViewController`. If you have created custom initialisation method for `HomeViewController`, declare this method in `HomeViewController` header file.